# tr command not working

Tags: sed, awk, tr

Hello every one here I have a problem. I have a  file in which there is some data like this

- mango
- apple
- orange
- grapes

When I run  the command

```
 tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt
```

It works fine; 
the output was:

```
 mango apple orange grapes
```

but I have another  file which has data like this

- 12029
- SIDRASHAHID
- 7(outof471)

but the above command is not working on it. Is the problem that the file has numerical data?

I have even tried sed but failed.

Can any one tell me if there is a way by which I can write this data into a single line?

Comment: What are you seeing?  Could the trouble be that the file has carriage returns in it (CRLF line endings from a Windows machine)?  If so, you probably see '7(outof471)' as the output.

Comment: yes sir it is because of carriage return thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a comment into an answer since it seems to be accurate:

> What are you seeing? Could the trouble be that the file has carriage returns in it (CRLF line endings from a Windows machine)? If so, you probably see '7(outof471)' as the output.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ cat file.txt 
12029
SIDRASHAHID
7(outof471)
```

use `echo $()`:

```sh
$ echo $(cat file.txt)
12029 SIDRASHAHID 7(outof471)
```

If you still *would like* to use `sed`, you can:

```sh
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta' file.txt 
12029 SIDRASHAHID 7(outof471)
```

Comment: Sir its only printing 7(outof471)

Comment: use the `sed` example I posted. Since your shell may not be ... "standard".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk '{printf $0}' yourFile
```